# Variable 'X' is used before it has been assigned a value?

Tags: vb.net

i have searched over it. but ain't any solution about this.
Error :- Variable 'pri' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime
this type is displays

```
Public Function writepacket(ByRef dataa As String, ByRef heading As String) As Object
        Dim logpath As Object
        logpath = "C:\ZASHIT.txt"
        Dim prit, x, ppp, pri As Object
        FileClose(1)
        If dataa = "JH" Then
            FileOpen(1, logpath, OpenMode.Append)
            PrintLine(1, " ")
            PrintLine(1, "/////////////////" & heading & "//////////////////")
            PrintLine(1, " ")
            FileClose(1)
        Else
            FileOpen(1, logpath, OpenMode.Append)
            PrintLine(1, heading)
            PrintLine(1, dataa & "              " & TimeOfDay)
            x = 1
            Do Until x = Len(dataa) + 1
                pri = **pri** & Asc(Mid(dataa, x, 1)) & " "
                ppp = Hex(Asc(Mid(dataa, x, 1)))
                If Len(ppp) = 1 Then ppp = "0" & ppp
                prit = **prit** & ppp & " "
                x = x + 1
            Loop
            PrintLine(1, pri & "    ---    " & TimeOfDay)
            PrintLine(1, prit & "    ---    " & TimeOfDay)
            PrintLine(1, " ")
            FileClose(1)
        End If
**End Function**
```

Comment: Try this: Dim prit, x, ppp, pri As Object = nothing;

Comment: Dim prit, x, ppp, pri As Object = "" this??

Comment: Do yourself a favour and turn on `Option Strict`.  Your function also doesn't return a value.

Comment: @Neil Chauchan, no, = Nothing. like 1st comment said.

Comment: no more errors increasing

Comment: so are there more or less errors? did it work?

Comment: @ this 3 place error is cming

Comment: Well, can you post the errors?

Comment: more error coming when i ma using Dim prit, x, ppp, pri As Object = nothing;

Comment: Why are you declaring everything As Object? You should not do this. Declare each variable as the correct type for its use. In the case of `Pri` this should be a string: `Dim Pri As String = ""`

Comment: yah but...that all variable are having same type.. or should i Declare Dim prit, x, ppp As Object     Dim pri As Object = nothing:?

Comment: yah perfect... its done Dim pri As Object = "" Dim prit As Object = "" was getting error @ Prit also... so i declared him separate

Answer (score 3):

VB.NET is not old visual basic.  Get used to being disciplined about types - using `Object` for all your variables is terrible practice.  Use `String` for strings, use `Integer` for integers, etc.

```
Public Sub writepacket(ByRef dataa As String, ByRef heading As String)
'Change to Sub - you're not writing a function - it's not returning anything
    Dim logpath As String         'Dim as String!
    logpath = "C:\ZASHIT.txt"
    Dim prit, ppp, pri As String  'Dim as String!
    Dim x As Integer              'Dim as Integer!
    FileClose(1)
    If dataa = "JH" Then
        FileOpen(1, logpath, OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, " ")
        PrintLine(1, "/////////////////" & heading & "//////////////////")
        PrintLine(1, " ")
        FileClose(1)
    Else
        FileOpen(1, logpath, OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, heading)
        PrintLine(1, dataa & "              " & TimeOfDay)
        x = 1
        pri = ""      'Initialize your string variables!
        prit = ""     'Initialize your string variables!
        Do Until x = dataa.Length + 1
        ' prefer string.Length property instead of Len()
            pri = pri & Asc(Mid(dataa, x, 1)).ToString() & " "
            ' use explicit conversions! -->  .ToString() 
            ppp = Hex(Asc(Mid(dataa, x, 1)))
            If ppp.Length = 1 Then ppp = "0" & ppp
            ' prefer string.Length property instead of Len()
            prit = prit & ppp & " "
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        PrintLine(1, pri & "    ---    " & TimeOfDay)
        PrintLine(1, prit & "    ---    " & TimeOfDay)
        PrintLine(1, " ")
        FileClose(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, consider getting rid of `FileOpen`, `FileClose`, `PrintLine`, etc - there are far better tools in the .NET toolbox.  `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` would be much better options :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Inherits Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.BaseOcxArray have solution about this? it was VB6 project before.. i converted it to VB 2008 then converted it to VB 2010

Comment: @NeilChauhan What does `BaseOcxArray` have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

in the Do Until youre assigning Pri to be Pri + "..."
as with every object you have to allocate memory and assign pri before using it.